# What does "Supported source version 'RELEASE_5' from annotation processor..." mean?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, sonatype, plexus

What does it mean and how it can be removed (reformatted for better readability)?

```
[INFO] Compiling 30 source files to ...\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_5' from annotation processor 
'org.sonatype.guice.bean.scanners.index.QualifiedIndexAPT6' 
less than -source '1.6'
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: 
org.junit.Ignore,org.junit.Test,org.junit.BeforeClass
```

This happens when `org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:2.1.1` is one of project dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first warning was removed after upgrading of `sisu-inject-plexus` up to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
  <artifactId>sisu-inject-plexus</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The second one after using `-Xlint:-processing` flag of [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) compiler:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-testCompile</id>
      <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:-processing</compilerArgument>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  <execution>
</plugin>
```

Otherwise, we can use

```
<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated warnings here. First, there's a class that claims it wants to look at annotations, but it only understands Java 5 syntax, and you've specified Java 6 syntax on the command line; and second, you've got some JUnit annotations in there, but nothing is looking at them.

They both sound fairly safe to ignore, but unfortunately whatever is trying to run `javac` here (is it `apt`?) is failing to understand the output.

Comment: Ernest, could you please explain what "nothing is looking at them" means?

Comment: This output is coming from `apt`, I imagine, the Annotation Processing Tool, the purpose of which is to find all the annotations in your code and make them available to plug-in "annotation processors". The tool is just warning you that some annotations exist for which no annotation processor is registered. This is not a   bad thing at all -- if you're not running JUnit at the moment, then nothing should care about those JUnit annotations.

Comment: Got it, but this message is sent by `javac` (being ran by Apache Maven 3.0.3 maven-compiler-plugin 2.4). Do you know what to do in order to remove the warning. Ignoring it is not an option for me.